# Then choose the correct option regarding Picard theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

let  $f$ be  a  non  constant  entire  function   and let $ E$  be  the image   of $ f$.
Then

choose the correct option

$1$. $E$  is  an open set

$2$. $E \cap \{z : |z| < 1\} $ is  empty

$3.$$E  \cap \mathbb{R}$ is  non empty

$4.$ $E$  is  a  bounded set

I know that  by open mapping theorem, only option $1)$ will be correct

im   confused  at  other  option

pliz help me....

Comment: Are we considering "points at infinity" to be a part of the complex plane? Either way, $E$, if bounded, is bounded only by directed infinities. I don't know about 2) and 3). Wouldn't you need to know more about the function to say if these were true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3) is also true. Picard's Theorem says if $f$ is a non-constant entire function then $E=\mathbb  C$ or $E=\mathbb  C \setminus \{c\}$ for some complex number $c$. So $E$ must contain all real numbers except possibly one. 2) and 4) are false: take $f(z)=z$ for 2) and use Louivile's Theorem for 4). Alternative argument for 3): If $E \cap \mathbb R =\emptyset$ then $E=E_1 \cup E_2$ where $E_1=\{z: Im\, z>0\}$ and $E_1=\{z: Im\, z<0\}$. This gives a  contradiction to the fact that $E$ is connected.